# Primary index vs Clustered index

Tags: indexing

Is it correct to say that clustered index is an index on a non-key value of a table of records while the records are sorted based on that attribute? Where as primary index is on an attribute that is a key for that table of records and table is sorted based on that attribute?

Comment: `Clustered index` determines how database table is internally structured.  `Non-clustered` index is a separate table that is linked to the main one.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx

Answer (score 6):

A clustered index is a special type of index that reorders the way records in the table are physically stored. Therefore table can have only one clustered index. The leaf nodes of a clustered index contain the data pages.

A primary index is an index on a set of fields that includes the unique primary key for the field and is guaranteed not to contain duplicates.

Primary key is not necessarily clustered index (although probably in 95% of scenarios it is), while Clustered index is not necessarily is primary key.

Comment: + Primary - not NULL

Comment: I can't agree with the following statement, "A primary index is an index on a set of fields that includes the unique primary key for the field and is guaranteed not to contain duplicates".

Primary indexing can be performed on any search key (not necessarily unique).

Answer (score 1):

In several websites is written that these definitions have a different meaning, but it's not written that in **Database System Concepts 7th Edition, by Silberschatz, Korth and Sudarshan**. In page 625, Chapter 14, Ordered Indices subject, we can see that have exactly the same meaning

[image]

So, it's a common case to have a *primary index* on a *primary key*, but it's not the right definition because it can appear in any other field

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, primary key is also clustered index. And it's purely depends upon implementation of database. In some of databases, whole record are structured as cluster index.